# iOS Push to TabBarController

Tags: ios, navigation

i have several viewcontrollers, and at the last viewcontroller, i want when the users click on a button present in this view, he goes on a other view controller which contains tabbarcontroller. [image: Example]

For example, i've something like this :

How can i go from the first view, to the tab bar controller ?

EDIT : i tried to just set a push from the button to the tab bar controller, but it's not runnin g correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a segue in the Interface Builder, give it a unique identifier, then call that segue in your code using

```
[self performSegue:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Comment: Segue to the Tab Bar Controller - it should essentially be the same as any other view controller because it inherits its definitions from `UIViewController`.

Comment: Yes i said a bullshit, it's running of course, there is only one problem, i need to delete my navigation controller from my first view.

Comment: i forgot to show it, but i have a navigation controller for the first view. (of course, i haven't just one view, it's just for the example)

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed the button's view controller in a `UINavigationController`, otherwise you will get an error like this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Once I put it in a `UINavigationController`, it transitioned just fine in my tests.

If you do not want a `UINavigationController`, you can set the segue to Modal, and it should also transition to the Tab Bar, but modally.