# tabbar is not displaying in secondview controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbar, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I am new in iOS world.I am creating one tab-bar sample app.

There is one button in first view-controller when i click this button it goes to to second view-controller.In second view-controller i use one `gridview` and i left 100 space at bottom.

now in second view-controller i have to add one tab bar so i go to `Editor->Embedin->Tabbar controller` and run application but i do not see tab bar here.I also try to use tab bar controller on object library but same issue i found.

**Why tab bar is not displaying in second view-controller.Any suggestion ?**

button click event :-

```
SecondVC *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Thanks .

Comment: Can you please post your code. Button click event

Comment: SecondVC *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: I guess, You are calling directly the second viewcontroller. That's why it is loading the second view controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748354/ios-push-to-tabbarcontroller

Comment: yes this is app requirement, second view controller has tabbar but it is not displaying. 
any suggestion how can i call second view controller with tab bar. I add tab bar controller on second view controller but why it is not displaying ? can you please help .

Comment: In short, you can't do it !

Comment: @Proton Actually it's my project requirement when i click one button in first view controller and then in second view controller have grid view with tab bar. Any suggestion

Comment: From 1st view controller, you should `present` to 2nd view controller. In 2nd VC, you can add new tabbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the SecondVC embedded in a TabBarVC you need to present the TBVC instead of the SecondVC in order for the Tab Bar to actually appear.

So instead of doing:

```
SecondVC *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

you need to do:

```
TabBarVC *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarVC"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

This will add to the navigation stack the Tab Bar View Controller.

This might be the implementation you are looking for
[image: TabBarVC inside NavC]

Comment: I have one more issue after this. After click on button it goes to tab bar now but when i press back button the application crash and show me this error:- "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
"
if i check it on google and change animation yes to no so it did not crash:- [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
but when i click on first time back button it goes to  again tabbar controller ie. embeded in second vc if i press second time back button now they go to first vc. any suggestion ?

Comment: @arpit I'm not sure I understood correctly the problem, but sounds like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21226801/2745324

Answer (score 0):

Button to viewcontroller SecondVC set segue identifer name as Pass

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Pass"])
{
SecondVC* vc = [[SecondVC alloc] init];
```

vc  = (SecondVC *) [[(UINavigationController*)[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

```
}
}
```